# Edit the category page in html source (1.8)

Tags: magento-1.8, category

The category page of my Magento 1.8 webshop.

There is a **display: none**  in the source on the category title in this div:

```
<div class="page-title category-title">
```

It's ok for me that this is invisble, but I don't like the **display: none** css solution. I prefer to delete this line/div from the source.

Only thing is I cannot find the file on the server that contains this.

Could anyone point me in good direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default is in app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/category/view.phtml

I suppose your Magento uses a custom template and you will need to change /base/default to {your_package}/{your_theme} to find the one that your system uses. If is not there then copy the base file to your theme following the same folder structure.